# how can I pass database name from batch to mysql script

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I am writing a Batch Script which takes list of credentials(dbname, ip, login, password) from a csv file and executes sql script using these values. I am able to do this in MS SQL Server but I am not able to pass these values dynamically in MYSQL.

Batch File:
*Database name is set in %dbname%*

```
mysql --host=%ip% --port=%port% --user=%user% --password=%pwd% --database=defaultdb < query.sql
```

query.sql:

```
select count(*) from x.test_table;
```

Instead of x, I want my database name from %dbname%

Comment: Ok. I have added the code along with the question.

Comment: doesn't `--database=defaultdb` do the job for you, by selecting the query's target database upon opening the connection? Or am I missing something here? Why do you still need the db.test_table?

Comment: Actually, there are two databases, one is default db is static, other one is variable. I need both.